# Total size of similar indices

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Kibana shows statistics for every index on the monitoring page [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0fMJ.png). How can we group indices by type to get their overall size? For example I've got a lot of `winlogbeat-6.2.2-YYYY.mm.dd` indices and would like to know how much space do all of them consume in total.
thanks!

Answer (score 4):

One way to achieve what you want is to use the [Index stats API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-stats.html), and filter out the `store.size_in_bytes` value, like this:

```
winlogbeat-6.2.2*/_stats?filter_path=_all.total.store.size_in_bytes
```

You'll get a response like this:

```
{
  "_all": {
    "total": {
      "store": {
        "size_in_bytes": 922069687976
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Another way to achieve what you want involves leveraging the [Cat APIs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat-indices.html), a bit of `grep` and a tad of `awk`...

The following shell command will give you the number of bytes consumed by all your `winlogbeat-6.2.2` indices:

```
curl -s localhost:9200/_cat/indices?bytes=b | grep winlogbeat-6.2.2 | awk '{s+=$9} END {print s}'
```

You'll get a single number, like this: `922069687976`

Let me explain:

The first command will retrieve all indices via the `_cat/indices` API.

```
curl -s localhost:9200/_cat/indices?bytes=b
```

The second command keeps only the indices matching `winlogbeat-6.2.2`

```
grep winlogbeat-6.2.2
```

The last command does the magic of summing up all numbers in the 9th column (i.e. `store.size`)

```
awk '{s+=$9} END {print s}'
```

Voilà...

Comment: Thank you for the hint with `?bytes=b`! I thought ES could deliver "user-friendly" format only - with `mb` and `gb`, I tweaked the suffixes with `awk`, but I was not nice. Using the `bytes` param gives you the exact size!

Comment: The grep can be dropped by moving indices wildcard into the URL resulting in:
curl -s "localhost:9200/_cat/indices/winlogbeat-6.2.2*?bytes=b" | awk '{s+=$9} END {print s}'

Answer (score 1):

If you collect monitoring stats for your cluster, when you could use Kibana for visualization:

**Prerequisites**: X-Pack which will be creating `.monitoring-*` indices.

Create a scripted field for the index pattern `.monitoring-es-6-*`:

Field name: `normalized_index_name` (will work for for `SOME-INDEX-YYYY.MM.DD` pattern only as it removes everything from the index name after the last dash, a scripted field with a regex can be used, but regex fields must be explicitly allowed in the ES config):

```
def name = doc['index_stats.index'].value;
if (name != null) {
    int lastDashIndex = name.lastIndexOf('-');
    if (lastDashIndex > 0) {
    return name.substring(0,lastDashIndex);
    }
}
return name
```

Create a *Line* visualization. Note:

- time frame should be set to 7 days
- start to build the visualization from X-axis, otherwise it may not split series properly (bug?..)!

[image]